# Why is Docusign Demo Integration key disabled (Color is grey not Green)?

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi

I have created a demo account and have generated an Integration Key, however the Status of they key says Demo(which is fine) but with a Grey color circle, now I know the live status says Active with Green circle but wondering if this is why I am getting the error below when I'm trying to Create an Envelope in C#.

> Additional information: Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
>
> "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
>
> "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is
>   disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
>
> }

I have implemented the authentication and I am not getting an error there using the same integration key.

```
var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
var envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
```

Comment: Which DocuSign URL are you using ? Test or Production ?

Comment: I use "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi" and I am assuming it is correct because I am able to authenticate.

Comment: It is correct. I have had the same error once because one of those values was wrong : UserName, Password, AccountId. Can youdouble check them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to pass in a Configuration object to the EnvelopesApi constructor. That did the trick.

```
string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + DocuSignCredentials.Username + "\",     \"Password\":\"" + DocuSignCredentials.Password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + DocuSignCredentials.IntegratorKey + "\"}";

Configuration configuration = new Configuration(new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi"));
if (configuration.DefaultHeader.ContainsKey("X-DocuSign-Authentication"))
{
    configuration.DefaultHeader.Remove("X-DocuSign-Authentication");
}
configuration.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(configuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to hit Demo and getting that error: Review your x-DocuSign-Authentication header and confirm the key is being passed correctly. You might use a tool like Fiddler to capture the raw packet to see what's going through.

An integrator key that has gone live to Production will still be valid in Demo.